# GtkWarning: Modulpath »clearlooks« no Themen-Engine found

Tags: linux, gtk2, ubuntu

German error-message: 
GtkWarning: Im Modulpfad »clearlooks« konnte keine Themen-Engine gefunden werden

If you start a Applikation on bash, you see this error. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On (K)Ubuntu you need only to do:

```
sudo aptitude install gtk2-engines
```